# How to check current location is withing our service range or not in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, location

I have a data in my table like this.

```
id, location, latitude, longitude
```

I used this to mange service area.

```
1, Ahmedabad, 23.0521705, 74.54970690000005
```

Now user's current location is your location.

Then I need to check your location is comes in my service area or not? I searched but I didn't get any idea. Can any one hellp me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `npm` then please install `node-geocoder`.

```
npm i node-geocoder
```

From this `npm` you can get address details from `lat long`.

```
geocoder.reverse({lat:45.767, lon:4.833}, function(err, res) {
   console.log(res);
});
```

Based on that you can use `LIKE` query in db to find that is there any location in which you provide service.

For more information please read this [URL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-geocoder)

Happy coding. :)